# Grabbing values from a dictionary in a more elegant way

Tags: swift

I've been playing with swift and am getting quite tortured! Consider:

```
var myDict : Dictionary <String, String>

//DO SOME MAGIC TO POPULATE myDict with values
<magic being done>


//Now myDict has values.  Let's parse out the values of myDict

//This doesn't work
let title : String  = myDict["title"]

//This does
let title : String? myDict["title"]
```

This is because it isn't known whether the key is in the dictionary.  What I want to say, though, is "If the title key is in the dictionary, give me that value, else, just give me an empty string"

I could probably write:

```
var myTitle : String
if let title : String = myDict["title"] {
    myTitle = title
} else {
    myTitle = ""
}
```

I believe that works...BUT...it's quite a lot of code for EACH key of the dictionary.  Does anyone have any ideas in the swift world on how this is supposed to be written?

RD

Answer (score 2):

You unwrap the value either explicitly:

```
let title : String  = myDict["title"]!
```

or implicitly:

```
let title : String!  = myDict["title"]
```

Note that you still have to check whether `title` is `nil` or not unless you are really sure it's there.

**Edit:**

Here's a sample global operator overload for any optional for type `T`:

```
@infix func | <T: Any>(lhs: T?, rhs: T!) -> T! {
    if lhs {
        return lhs!
    }
    return rhs
}

var myDict : Dictionary <String, String> = ["a": "b"]

let title1  = (myDict["a"] | "") // "b"
let title2  = (myDict["title"] | "") // ""
```

Comment: Hmm.  Explicitly unwrapping it leaves me with a nil if the value isn't present.  My goal would be to default back to a value of the explicit unwrapping would return nil.

Comment: OK I missed your empty string requirement. drewag's answer provides a solution then. Too bad we couldn't overload a `func ?:(...)`

Answer (score 2):

You could write an extension on optional:

```
extension Optional {
    /// Unwrap the value returning 'defaultValue' if the value is currently nil
    func or(defaultValue: T) -> T {
        switch(self) {
            case .None:
                return defaultValue
            case .Some(let value):
                return value
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
myDict["title"].or("")
```

This would also work for all optionals.

**Note**: I started a [module](https://github.com/drewag/SwiftPlusPlus) to add common helpers like this `or` on `Optional` to swift.